# Non-linear solver in R (log-linear distribution)

Tags: r

I need help in preparing something similar to Solver (from Excel) in R.

I try to develop a tool, which will take some points and create parameters of curve suitable for them. This curve will have a shape of log-linear distribution. I need 4 parameters, which could be useable in Excel formula:
`y = b*loglindist(x*a, c, d)`, where b is a parameter using for the result, a is a parameter using for a value of distribution, c is a mean, and d is a standard deviation.
I have to minimize sse between actual points and points estimated with the curve.

My code is as follows:

```
input <- read.csv2("C:/Users/justyna.andrulewicz/Desktop/R estimator/data.csv", sep=",")
data <- as.matrix(input)
x <- nrow(data)
max_reach <- 90   ### max y

# solver
 # constrains
a_min <- 0.000000001
b_min <- 0.5*max_reach
c_min <- 0.000000001
d_min <- 0.000000001
a_max <- 1000
b_max <- max_reach
c_max <- 1000
d_max <- 1000
constrains <- round(matrix(c(a_min,b_min,c_min,d_min,a_max,b_max,c_max,d_max), nrow=2, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(c("mins", "maxes"), c("a","b","c","d"))),1)
constrains

ui <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0, -1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,-1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,-1,0, 0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,-1), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
ci <- round(c(a_min, -a_max, b_min, -b_max, c_min, -c_max, d_min, -d_max), 1) 

a <- 100
b <- 0.4*max_reach
c <- 1
d <- 1
par <-as.numeric(c(a,b,c,d))
par

spends <- as.numeric(data[,1])
estimated <- b*plnorm(a*spends, meanlog = c, sdlog = d, log = FALSE)
actual <- as.numeric(data[,2])
se <- estimated-actual

sse <- function(se) sum(se^2)
sse(se)
optimization <- constrOptim(par, sse, NULL, ui, ci, method="SANN")
results<-round(as.numeric(optimization$par,nrow=4,ncol=1),6)
results
```

but it doesn't work: the results make no sense, as you can see in the plot.

```
step <- 10^3 
y <- 1:100 
spends<-y*step

a_est<-optimization$par[1]
b_est<-optimization$par[2]
c_est<-optimization$par[3]
d_est<-optimization$par[4]
curve<-b_est*plnorm(a_est*spends, meanlog = c_est, sdlog = d_est, log = FALSE)

est <-plot(spends, curve, type="l", col="blue")
act <-plot(data, type="p", col="red")
```

Please help: maybe can I replace constOptim and use another function, which will better address my problem? Or maybe there is another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Hi! It would be good if you posted at least a sample of your input csv data plus the results you expect. Thanks.

Comment: Good point, thank you! It is possible to add csv file there? How can I do it?

Comment: Not here, no. But you can post it anywhere else and link it here, if the full csv is needed. If not, it would be better if you just show a few rows (but in that case I guess it will be more difficult to post the expected result for just those few rows...) You can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) more details on the problem of reproducible examples.